# I don't understand this syntax error in python

Tags: python

```
print list(prolog.query(code))
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

can anyone tell me what does this syntax error mean?

I tried to install but it doesn't work.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: python 3.8.6 Do I need to use the latest python version or old version?

Comment: Then the syntax is print(...)

Answer (score 0):

check which python version you are using.

The code shown in question is valid until python 2.7, but not in Python 3 onward.

valid for Python 3:

```
print(list(prolog.query(code)))
```

(note the additional parenthesis like any function for `print`).

And as general advice, as noticed in comments, a syntax error marked at a line could be confusing and caused by a problem on the line before. Comment the line where you have the error and check.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not valid in python 3.x

But this is valid in 2.x

1. Change the syntax to `print(list(prolog.query(code))` (recommended)
2. or, Change your python version to 2.x (Not recommended)

Check this [`article`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_basic_syntax.htm).

Comment: Option 1 is a spectacularly bad idea :-) We should not really be trying to convince people to go back to Python2.

Comment: I will swap the option,